# How can I get the RGB or aRGB codes of background colors for each cell in an xlsx or xlsm file using openpyxl in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

## How to get the background color for each cell in xlsx or xlsm file using openpyxl python3

I need RGB or aRGB of background cell.

##### data look like this

[image]

I try

```py
wb = load_workbook(path)
cell = wb["sheet_name"].cell(row=row_number, column=column_number)
```

when I run the command below.

```py
cell.fill.start_color
```

I got

```py
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='FFffb600', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'
```

In this case, I get aRGB with `cell.fill.start_color.index`. It return `FFffb600`. That is the correct value.

but when the color type is `indexed`

```py
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=38, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='indexed'
```

I got index instead.

Next step. I go to https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#indexed-colour, then map the index with #Indexed Colours but the result not match.

how to fix it?

---

I try to use ChatGPT but it dosen't work.

package `xlrd` not working bacause it not supported xlsx file.

Thank for every answer.

---

Answer :

```py
wb._colors[cell.fill.start_color.index]
```

Comment: You need to look at the colours in the workbook styles.

Comment: thank . I got it `wb._colors[cell.fill.start_color.index]`

Comment: thank please write it as an answer. I will accept it